# GNU Assembler works on Linux, not on Windows

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler

I have this question on why the following GNU Assemlber(GAS) Code works on Ubuntu 16.04 , but when i run the same command it dosent work on windows(i will show error at end):

functions.S:

```
#
#           POWER FUNCTION
#           ---------------
#EAX - BASE
#EDI - EXP
# 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 2^5

.section .data


.section .text

    .globl _start

        _start:
                movl $1, %ebx
                pushl $2
                pushl $5
                call _powr
                jmp _eof

                .type _powr,@function
                _powr:
                    pushl %ebp
                    movl  %esp, %ebp
                    subl  $4, %esp
                    movl 8(%ebp),%edi
                    movl 12(%ebp) , %eax
                    call _powr_loop
                    movl %ebp, %esp
                    popl %ebp
                    ret
                .type _powr_loop,@function
                _powr_loop:
                    cmp $0,%edi
                    je _return
                    #ebx = ebx * eax
                    imull %eax,%ebx
                    decl %edi
                    jmp _powr_loop

                _return:
                    ret
                _eof:
                     mov $1, %eax
                     int $0x80
```

Makefile:

```
all:
    gcc -m32 functions.S -g -o exe -nostdlib
get_ebx:
    echo $?
```

. Well this runs perfectly fine on Linux , and when i do echo $? , it gives me the desired output 32 . BUT When i compile it on Windows i get this:

```
C:/BlahBLah/BlahBlah>gcc -m32 functions.S -g -o exe -nostdlib
functions.S: Assembler messages:
functions.S:22: Warning: .type pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef ignored.
functions.S:22: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `_'
functions.S:35: Warning: .type pseudo-op used outside of .def/.endef ignored.
functions.S:35: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `p'
```

And also, what is the echo$? For Windows? Help would be appreciated!

### EDIT

WinMain:

```
#
#           POWER FUNCTION
#           ---------------
#EAX - BASE
#EDI - EXP
# 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 = 2^5

.section .data


.section .text

    .globl _WinMain 

        _WinMain:
                movl $1, %ebx
                pushl $2
                pushl $5
                call _powr
                jmp _eof

                _powr:
                    pushl %ebp
                    movl  %esp, %ebp
                    subl  $4, %esp
                    movl 8(%ebp),%edi
                    movl 12(%ebp) , %eax
                    call powr_loop
                    movl %ebp, %esp
                    popl %ebp
                    ret;


                powr_loop:
                    cmp $0,%edi
                    je _return
                    #ebx = ebx * eax
                    imull %eax,%ebx
                    decl %edi
                    jmp powr_loop

                _return:
                    ret
                _eof:
                    call _exit
```

Comment: The `.type` pseudo directives don't apply to non-ELF objects. Because you are on Windows, GCC/LD don't use ELF so you can't use `.type _powr,@function` and `.type _powr_loop,@function` . Just remove those lines from your code and try again.

Comment: `mov $1, %eax` `int $0x80` only applies to Linux not Windows. `int 0x80` will crash your Windows application. You need to call the Win32 ExitProcess function.

Comment: @MichaelPetch hmm. Your right, which is the Win32 ExitProcess? And what is the echo$? for windows?

Comment: `echo %ERRORLEVEL%`

Comment: I recommend to make your life easier that you use the _C_ library. Change all `_start` to `_main`, remove the `.type` directives and then replace `mov $1, %eax int $0x80` with `call _exit` and the compile with `gcc -m32 functions.S -g -o exe`

Comment: @MichaelPetch when i compile it following you i get 
C:\BlahBlahBlah>gcc -m32 functions.S -g -o exe
c:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Same thing @MichaelPetch :( . 
C:\Blehhh>gcc -m32 functions.S -mno-windows  -g -o exed
c:/mingw/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: If you are building a Windows application, you need to provide an entry point. That entry point is, by convention, [`WinMain`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559.aspx). The C runtime libraries enforce that convention. If you want to use a different entry point, you need to specify that on the command line. But don't. Use the standard one, as documented. Windows and Linux are different. Don't try to treat them as if they are the same. You will not get very far. Focus on learning assembly on *one* platform; learn the other platform once you're comfortable.

Comment: Still the same @MichaelPetch :(

Comment: @CodyGray i followed your WinMain thing and it suprisingly worked! BUT , when i do echo %ERRORLEVEL%  . its giving me 5 instead of 32

Comment: @MichaelPetch ^^ I will update the code with the new WinMain

Comment: Oops you need to PUSH your result as the argument to `_exit` before calling `_exit`. In your case that appears to be `push %ebx` `call _exit`

Comment: Yup That worked. Thanks @MichaelPetch !

Comment: Well, don't expect a Windows application to set `%ERRORLEVEL%`. This is a console application thing *only*. A standard Windows application doesn't use an error level. (It might work, but it isn't guaranteed. You have no idea if the runtime environment is going to do some cleanup and return a different error code.) If you want to use this, you need to be building a console application. Those have a different entry point, and will require different linker flags to get the correct flags set in the PE image.

Comment: On a unrelated note @MichaelPetch ,  can you explain me why im getting 0 , as the result when im doing echo$? (Using Ubuntu)? Its suppose to be a factorial and is !10 : https://gist.github.com/amanuel2/9884ba759d4add9cb6569ecd158c4a36  . Thanks a lot!

Comment: @CodyGray Im just starting Assembly , and learning using this recomended by Peter Cordes : http://programminggroundup.blogspot.com/2007/01/chapter-4-all-about-functions.html  .  Im thinking it will teach me how to "printf()" later? not sure.

Comment: I'm sure it will. But that is clearly a Linux-based tutorial, yet all of your questions are about how to make it run on Windows. You are doing it wrong!

Comment: @CodyGray : Which I asked earlier how they installed MinGW. I am able to create a proper console application with a `_main` entry point here that has been properly called from the _C_ runtime environment MinGW would be using and should properly return an address via `_exit`.

Comment: You are using the right linker flags, @Michael. :-) Honestly, I'm not very familiar with MinGW, but if I remember correctly, you just want `-mconsole`. That gets you an app that targets the console subsystem, which by convention uses the `_main` entry point. And does all the nice console-y stuff, like `%ERRORLEVEL%`.

Comment: Regarding your problem with Linux and your factorial program. Without seeing your code I will bet that you don't set _EBX_ to the return value when using `mov $1, %eax` `int 0x80`. Also I think on Linux the return value is limited to 0-255 so 10 factorial will not fit and be truncated.

Comment: Oh , yes.. I always forget that @MichaelPetch ! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MichaelPetch: yes, Linux return values are 8bit, because they're packed into an `int` with a bunch of other flags.  See `WEXITSTATUS` in the [`wait(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) man page.